# Graph unclear, how to to rapresent very different sized columns in Excel?

Tags: excel, graph

[image: The Graph]

I considered having a seconday axis for the first two columns as they are too different from the others, but in the excel combo graph I can do that only by date series instead of municipality. Thank you in advance for your ideas!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming, but about representation of data.

Comment: Just convert the 0-300 scale to a log scale.. That should settle the sizing part. | format axis > log scale..